# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, encoding, chunked-encoding

I have an issue when I load any post like woocommerce, edit product page in admin side, nothing was shown and in console it gives an error:

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200
```

Please help me to solve this error.

**Note: It is not a browser specific. I have this issue in all browsers.**

Comment: Is it your website on Nginx server?

Comment: @dipmala no it is on apache.

Comment: Got the same issue on one of my client's website. Did  you find a solution? Thank you

Comment: @CharlesMorin try to update visual builder version or remove and add it again.
Actually i tried it and it solved my problem. Because I am using enfold theme and it gives me theme builder already and then when i use visual builder it gives me this error so when i remove visual builder and add it again then solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was one of my plugins.
To solve, I renamed the folder wp-content/plugins to wp-content/plugins_old.
So I was able to login in wp-admin/ and check what plugins needed to be fixed.

I hope this help anyone.